# After adding float:left the layout is not the way is supposed to be

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to add two div containers into another one. One floating on the left and the other one on to the right side of the main container. The problem is, if I add float:left on the first div, it's no longer contained in the main container.
Before adding float: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlV6D.jpg
After adding it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7q4ST.jpg
HTML:

```
<div class="container"> 

       <div class="column1">
           
           <div class="rowTop">
               <p>Community</p>
           </div>

           <div class="row">
               <div id="leftSide"> 
                  <h3><a>Disscusion</a></h3>
                  <p>&#8594 Disscusions about various games like Warframe or HuntShowdown</p>
               </div>
               <div id="rightSide">
                   0:Threds
               </div>
           </div>

           <div class="row">
           </div>

           <div class="row">
           </div>

       </div>

       <div class="column2">

       </div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
margin:30px;
}

.column1{
width:70%;
float:left;
}
.column2{
width:15%;
float:right;
padding:2px;
}
.rowTop{
background-color: rgb(0, 51, 0);
border:1px solid white;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
width:10%;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: black 1px 1px;
color:white;
}

.row{
background-color: black;
border:1px solid white;
color:white;
display: block;
padding:0;
}

.row #leftSide{
color:white;
float: left;
margin-right: 0;
width: 55%;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.
Please don't  give me any hate, I'm new to coding :3

Comment: Please post a mark up image of your desired result

Comment: I was able to replicate your issue, but instead of explaining you the problem, I would rather discourage you from using floats for structuring the layout. Floats were used for it the past, but they can get very messy. Nowadays with CSS3 there is more options, so I would rather advice you to check grid or flexbox, which are modern (and more powerful) approaches of structuring the layout.

Comment: I have answer saved in draft I knowthe furstration of it all trying to develope a visioned GUI of sorts ...... could you please illustrate as in what your expected out come would be what I am assuming is as following a) you have warper container with in which are two columns b) then first solumn aka leftside is then devided into two columns c) you expect each of the coumns in a and b to appear next to each other in placement horizontaly rather than vetically?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flexbox for this. [Check out the guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for your CSS. Just change the display to `flex`:

```
.row{
    background-color: black;
    border:1px solid white;
    color:white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row
    padding:0;
}
```